# C# COM NLA error HRESULT 0x80040202

Tags: c#, events, com, error-code

Ok so I am trying to set up a Network Connection event using `NetworkListManager` from `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes` using this code:

```
private NetworkListManager nlm; //This is initialized before
private IConnectionPoint icp;
private int cookie = 0;

//This part is wrapped in a function call
Console.WriteLine("Subscribing the INetworkListManagerEvents");
IConnectionPointContainer icpc = (IConnectionPointContainer)nlm;
Guid tempGuid = typeof(INetworkListManagerEvents).GUID;
icpc.FindConnectionPoint(ref tempGuid, out icp);
//The error is thrown in icp.Advise with code 0x80040202
icp.Advise(this, out cookie);
```

I've already tried searching, but most people are concerned about different matters on this error

Comment: We can't see what the `this` object declaration looks like.  Forgetting to implement INetworkListManagerEvents or omitting [ComVisible(true)] are the standard mistakes that cause this error.  Do avoid doing this the hard way, using the standard C# += operator to subscribe events works for COM events as well.

Comment: Post your comment as answer so I can upvote. It works and thank you very much!

Comment: I cannot post the correct answer from incomplete info.  You can just post it yourself and mark it as the answer.

Comment: ok, I will edit the post make it as clear as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of using the `NETWORKLIST` is like this:

```
using NETWORKLIST;

public class Foo : INetworkListManagerEvents 
{
    private NetworkListManager nlm; 
    private IConnectionPoint icp;
    private int cookie = 0;

    public Foo()
    {
        nlm = new NetworkListManager();
        IConnectionPointContainer icpc = (IConnectionPointContainer)nlm;
        Guid tempGuid = typeof(INetworkListManagerEvents).GUID;
        icpc.FindConnectionPoint(ref tempGuid, out icp);
        icp.Advise(this, out cookie);
    }

    //this method must be implemented
    public void ConnectivityChanged(NLM_CONNECTIVITY newConnectivity)
    {
        //Your code goes here
    }
}
```

What I was doing wrong is that I forgot to implement `INetworkListManagerEvents`